# ClassCastException: com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.DefaultListType cannot be cast to class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.SetType

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, datastax

until the migration from spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.8 to 2.5.2
I got the following error and I don't find the solution.

When I execute a save on my reactives repostiories, I got the following error below, and I don't find any solution. Anyone else have a solution please ?

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.DefaultListType cannot be
> cast to class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.SetType
> (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.DefaultListType and
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.SetType are in unnamed module of
> loader 'app') Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.DefaultListType cannot be
> cast to class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.SetType
> (com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.DefaultListType and
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.SetType are in unnamed module of
> loader 'app')     at
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.inspectType(CachingCodecRegistry.java:359)
> at
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:256)
> at
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.data.ValuesHelper.encodePreparedValues(ValuesHelper.java:112)
> at
> com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultPreparedStatement.boundStatementBuilder(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:187)
> at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.PreparedStatementDelegate.bind(PreparedStatementDelegate.java:51)
> at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.ReactiveCassandraTemplate$PreparedStatementHandler.bindValues(ReactiveCassandraTemplate.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactiveCqlTemplate.lambda$null$6(ReactiveCqlTemplate.java:577)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:152)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8221)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:82)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2251)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:143)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.subscribe(MonoCompletionStage.java:57)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4135)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:74)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:203)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4135)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:93)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8408)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8205)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8129)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8047)     at
> fr.contractsink.services.ContractConsumer.receive(ContractConsumer.java:71)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
> at
> org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:347)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2319)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2300)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2214)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2139)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2021)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1703)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1264)
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)   at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

The only dependency declared for cassandra in my pom.xml is:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMjCe.png)
Thank a lot and best best regards,
Adrien

Comment: check schema of table with your code - it looks like your trying to use List for Set, or vice versa

Comment: @AlexOtt no sorry the entity and the schema doesn't change about 3 years ago ...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The problem was the repository has parameter of Collection type that was used in the IN predicate for the query.

For that parameter sometimes Set was passed, sometimes list, and HashSet caused the problem. I've changed Collection to List in the repository method signature, added coversion to the list for Set, and everything started to work.